# application not running on a device in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, xcode4.1

Everytime I run my application in Xcode 4.2 with iOs 5, Xcode says it finished running on my device but actually it doesn't build there, it just finished running. But when I run my application in Xcode 4.1 it runs in my device. by the way, my device is an ipod Touch 2nd gen with an iOs version of 4.2.1. Can anyone suggest what must be causing the problem? thanks

Comment: Do you have your iOS deployment target set to iOS 4? It is set to the current, highest major iOS version by default, so in Xcode 4.1, that would be iOS 4 while in Xcode 4.2, that would be iOS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project target -> build settings

In the field "Architectures", add "armv6" and you should able to build and run the app with armv6 device s

Comment: I've tried to add armv6 in the field "Architectures" but still it does not run and build in the device. By the way, my valid architectures were armv6 and armv7.